# How to play ad before video through chromecast using IMA sdk?

Tags: android, chromecast, imasdk

i am developing a streaming app in which i have implemented chromecast functionality.Everything is working fine but the only issue is when a content video have pre roll ad then either ad is skipped and content video is played if we connected with chromecast or ad is locally played and after that content video is played through chromecast.My question is can we play both ad and content video through chromecast using IMA sdk because manually it is possible and i have done this but with IMA sdk there no luck.My code is as :

```
public class ClassChromeCast {
    Context context;
    public ClassChromeCast(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }
    /**
     * Chromecast
     * */
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
    public static MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
    public MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback;
    private CastDevice mSelectedDevice;
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;
    private RemoteMediaPlayer mRemoteMediaPlayer;
    private Cast.Listener mCastClientListener;
    public static boolean mIsPlaying,mIsFinished,mApplicationStarted = false,mVideoIsLoaded,isConnected = false;
    private boolean mWaitingForReconnect = false,temp = false,temp2 = false;
    /**
     * Local variable
     */
    private static String videoUrl = "",videoTitle = "" ,videoAdUrl = "";
    private RSSFeed_Addsplay rssFeed_AddsplayObj;
    /*======================Chromecast=======================*/
    public void initMediaRouter() {
        // Configure Cast device discovery
        mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(context);
        mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                .addControlCategory( CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast( context.getString( R.string.app_id ) ) )
                .build();
        mMediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouterCallback();
    }

    /**inner class MediaRouterCallback **/
    private class MediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {

        @Override
        public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteSelected");
            initCastClientListener();
            initRemoteMediaPlayer();
            mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle( info.getExtras() );
            launchReceiver();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRouteUnselected( MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo info ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRouteUnselected");
            //teardown();
            mSelectedDevice = null;
            //isConnected = false;
            //mVideoIsLoaded = false;
        }
    }

    /**---------------to initialize CastClientListener---------------*/
    private void initCastClientListener() {
        mCastClientListener = new Cast.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationStatusChanged() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onApplicationStatusChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onVolumeChanged() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onVolumeChanged");
            }

            @Override
            public void onApplicationDisconnected( int statusCode ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onApplicationDisconnected");
                teardown();
            }
        };
    }

    /**---------------to initialize RemoteMediaPlayer---------------*/
    private void initRemoteMediaPlayer() {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer = new RemoteMediaPlayer();
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnStatusUpdatedListener( new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnStatusUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusUpdated() {
                try{
                    MediaStatus mediaStatus = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaStatus();
                    mIsPlaying = mediaStatus.getPlayerState() == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_PLAYING;
                    mIsFinished = mediaStatus.getPlayerState() == MediaStatus.PLAYER_STATE_IDLE;
                    Log.d(TAG,"IsPlaying==="+mIsPlaying+"IsFinished===="+mIsFinished);
                    if(mIsFinished && temp && !temp2){
                         //temp = false;
                        Log.e("startVideo2","===");
                        startVideo(videoUrl,videoTitle);
                        temp2 = true;
                    }

                    if(mIsPlaying){
                         temp = true;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnMetadataUpdatedListener( new RemoteMediaPlayer.OnMetadataUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMetadataUpdated() {
                Log.d(TAG,"====mIsFinished");
            }
        });
    }

    private void launchReceiver() {
        Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions
                .builder( mSelectedDevice, mCastClientListener );

        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks mConnectionCallbacks = new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Connected");
                isConnected = true;
                if( mWaitingForReconnect ) {
                    mWaitingForReconnect = false;
                    reconnectChannels( bundle );
                } else {
                    try {
                        Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient,context.getString(R.string.app_id), false)
                                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult>() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onResult(Cast.ApplicationConnectionResult applicationConnectionResult) {
                                                           Status status = applicationConnectionResult.getStatus();
                                                           if (status.isSuccess()) {
                                                               mApplicationStarted = true;
                                                               reconnectChannels(null);
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                );
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                Log.e(TAG,"onConnectionSuspended");
                isConnected = false;
                mWaitingForReconnect = true;
            }
        };

        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener mConnectionFailedListener = new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");
                isConnected = false;
                teardown();
            }
        };

        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi( Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build() )
                .addConnectionCallbacks( mConnectionCallbacks )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener( mConnectionFailedListener )
                .build();

        mApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void reconnectChannels( Bundle hint ) {
        if( ( hint != null ) && hint.getBoolean( Cast.EXTRA_APP_NO_LONGER_RUNNING ) ) {
            Log.e( TAG, "App is no longer running" );
            Log.d(TAG, "reconnectChannels");
            teardown();
        } else {
            try {
                Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks( mApiClient, mRemoteMediaPlayer.getNamespace(), mRemoteMediaPlayer );
            } catch( IOException e ) {
                Log.e( TAG, "Exception while creating media channel ", e );
            } catch( NullPointerException e ) {
                Log.e( TAG, "Something wasn't reinitialized for reconnectChannels" );
            }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void teardown() {
        if( mApiClient != null ) {
            if( mApplicationStarted ){
                try {
                    Cast.CastApi.stopApplication( mApiClient );
                    if( mRemoteMediaPlayer != null ) {
                        Cast.CastApi.removeMessageReceivedCallbacks( mApiClient, mRemoteMediaPlayer.getNamespace() );
                        mRemoteMediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                } catch( Exception e ) {
                    Log.e( TAG, "Exception while removing application " + e );
                }
                mApplicationStarted = false;
            }
            if( mApiClient.isConnected() )
                mApiClient.disconnect();
            mApiClient = null;
        }
        mSelectedDevice = null;
        mVideoIsLoaded = false;
    }

    /**----to play video remotely-----*/

    public void playOnRemoteMediaPlayer(String title,String url, String adUrl){
        Log.e("OnRemoteMediaPlayer","adUrl=="+adUrl);
        try{
            rssFeed_AddsplayObj = new RSSFeed_Addsplay(adUrl + System.currentTimeMillis());
            videoAdUrl = rssFeed_AddsplayObj.getAdUrl();
        }catch (Exception e){
            videoAdUrl = "";
        }

        if(!mVideoIsLoaded && !videoUrl.equals(url)){
            videoUrl = url;
            videoTitle = title;
            temp2 = false;
            temp = false;
            if (videoAdUrl != null && videoAdUrl.length() > 0){
                Log.e("IF","===");
                startVideo(videoAdUrl,"Your program begin after this ad break");
            } else {
                Log.e("ELSE","===");
                startVideo(videoUrl,videoTitle);
            }
            //playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_av_pause_over_video_large);
        } else {
            controlVideo(videoUrl,videoTitle);
            if(mIsPlaying){
                //playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_av_play_over_video_large);
            }else {
                //playPauseBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_av_pause_over_video_large);
            }
        }
    }

    private void startVideo(String url, String s) {
        Log.e(TAG,"===startVideo"+url);
        TVE_HomeActivity.tvVideoLoadingText.setText(context.getString(R.string.playtext));
        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata( MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE );
        mediaMetadata.putString( MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE,s);
        MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(url)
                .setContentType("video/mp4")
                .setStreamType( MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED )
                .setMetadata( mediaMetadata )
                .build();

        try {
            mRemoteMediaPlayer.load( mApiClient, mediaInfo, true )
                    .setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult( RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult ) {
                            if( mediaChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess() ) {
                                mVideoIsLoaded = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            isConnected = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void controlVideo(String url, String title) {
        TVE_HomeActivity.tvVideoLoadingText.setText(context.getString(R.string.pausetext));
        try{
            if( mRemoteMediaPlayer == null || !mVideoIsLoaded )
                return;

            if( mIsPlaying ) {
                mRemoteMediaPlayer.pause( mApiClient );
            } else if(mIsFinished){
                Log.d(TAG,"Finished===true");
                startVideo(url,title);
            } else {
                mRemoteMediaPlayer.play( mApiClient );
            }
            Log.d(TAG,"running==="+mIsFinished);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried asking in this [forum](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/cast/client-side/community)? It is an IMA SDK and Google Cast Community, may be you can try asking it there too.

Comment: Yes,i have but no reply :(

Comment: @user7629803 Any solution for this issue, I experienced absolutely the same, is the IMA SDK for Android working with Casting (ChromeCast, MiraCast etc.)